# Problem synchronizing with ManualResetEvent

Tags: c#, synchronization, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7

I have written a method that downloads some files, and now I'm trying to make it download up to 5 files in parallel, and for the rest to wait for the previous ones to finish.
I am using a ManualResetEvent for this, but when i include the syncronisation part it doesn't download anything anymore (without it it works).

Here is the code of the methods:

```
    static readonly int maxFiles = 5;
    static int files = 0;
    static object filesLocker = new object();
    static System.Threading.ManualResetEvent sync = new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(true);

    /// <summary>
    /// Download a file from wikipedia asynchronously
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filename"></param>
    public void DoanloadFileAsync(string filename)
    {
        ...
        System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
            (o) =>
            {
                bool loop = true;
                while (loop)
                    if (sync.WaitOne())
                        lock (filesLocker)
                        {
                            if (files < maxFiles)
                            {
                                ++files;
                                if (files == maxFiles)
                                    sync.Reset();
                                loop = false;
                            }
                        }
                try
                {
                    WebClient downloadClient = new WebClient();
                    downloadClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(downloadClient_OpenReadCompleted);
                    downloadClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute));
                    //5 of them do get here
                }
                catch
                {
                    lock (filesLocker)
                    {
                        --files;
                        sync.Set();
                    }
                    throw;
                }
            });
    }

    void downloadClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //but none of the 5 get here
            ...Download logic... //works without the ManualResetEvent
        }
        finally
        {
            lock (filesLocker)
            {
                --files;
                sync.Set();
            }
        }
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong?

**It is written with Silverlight 4 for Windows Phone 7.**

Edit: **There is no Semaphore or SemaphoreSlim in Silverlight 4.**

Comment: Why lock when you can use the `System.Threading.Interlocked.Decrement()` method, etc. ?

Comment: Because I also want to call sync.Set(), and I think someone cold call sync.Set() from another thread,then I decrement, some threads increment and call sync.Reset(), then I call sync.Set() and I get more that maxFiles threads downloading.

Comment: Check my answer, it's what you are looking for. Also, using a reset event is OK, I just don't see the need for the locks. Oh and I use AutoResetEvent, because it is exactly what you need here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I meant in my comment was while use a slow `lock` when you can use `Interlocked`. Also it will be way more performant this way.

At most 5 downloads active in parallel:

```
public class Downloader
{
 private int fileCount = 0;
 private AutoResetEvent sync = new AutoResetEvent(false);

 private void StartNewDownload(object o)
 {
  if (Interlocked.Increment(ref this.fileCount) > 5) this.sync.WaitOne();

  WebClient downloadClient = new WebClient();
  downloadClient.OpenReadCompleted += downloadClient_OpenReadCompleted;
  downloadClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(o.ToString(), UriKind.Absolute));
 }

 private void downloadClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
 {
  try
  {
   // Download logic goes here.
  }
  catch {}
  finally
  {
   this.sync.Set();
   Interlocked.Decrement(ref this.fileCount);
  }
 }

 public void Run()
 {
  string o = "url1";
  System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(this.StartNewDownload, o);
  Thread.Sleep(100);

  o = "url2";
  System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(this.StartNewDownload, o);

  o = "url3";
  System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(this.StartNewDownload, o);
  Thread.Sleep(200);

  o = "url4";
  System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(this.StartNewDownload, o);

  o = "url5";
  System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(this.StartNewDownload, o);

  o = "url6";
  System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(this.StartNewDownload, o);

  o = "url7";
  System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(this.StartNewDownload, o);
  Thread.Sleep(200);

  o = "url8";
  System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(this.StartNewDownload, o);
  Thread.Sleep(400);
 }
}
```

Comment: The class should have been static (the code works for static sync as well).

Comment: Yes, it's more performant this way...but I still have the same problem ... maybe it is not from the AutoResetEvent / ManualResetEvent.

Comment: @user182945: Have you even tried my code? It can never reach 5+ concurrent downloads. If your callbacks are not executed, maybe the problem is elsewhere. Maybe it is something in your download logic. I have it empty for testing and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to limit the number of threads that can enter your critical section, the file download, at once. Rather than trying to hand craft this, use a `System.Threading.Semaphore` - that's what it does!

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a semaphore in Silverlight for Windows Phone.
Is there anything else similar to a semaphore I can use?

Comment: ahh - yes - sorry - maybe not. I was looking at the documentation for the full framework. I have found a few useful links here where people discuss alternatives in Silverlight:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307844/silverlight-dealing-with-async-calls and http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/20199/69433.aspx

Comment: Rob is correct; you're using the wrong synchronization primitive. If you're using .NET 4.0, use the `System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim` instead - it's lightweight, fast, and supports cancellation tokens, a feature you might find useful when doing long running operations like downloading files. EDIT: Took to long to type...

Comment: @Allon Guralnek Does this exist in Silverlight?

Comment: @Allon Guralnek There is no Semaphore or SempahoreSlim in Silverlight 4.
@Rob Levine I'll check those links.

Comment: Looking at the disassembly of SemaphoreSlim via Reflector, you might be able to just copy-paste the whole class into your project - internally it uses a ManualResetEvent: http://pastebin.com/cFmgihdB The reason for excluding many things out of Silverlight is usually to keep the download size of the Silverlight plug-in small, rather than technical reasons. Reflector is a great way to make up for these missing bits (when it works).

Answer (score 0):

By the looks the `WaitOne()` is hit before you are creating the `WebClient`. Since all the code that calls `Set()` is inside the event handler or exception handler it will never hit.

Perhaps you by mistake included the `WebClient` code inside the thread pool thread method which should be outside of it

```
    System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
        (o) =>
        {
            bool loop = true;
            while (loop)
                if (sync.WaitOne())
                    lock (filesLocker)
                    {
                        if (files < maxFiles)
                        {
                            ++files;
                            if (files == maxFiles)
                                sync.Reset();
                            loop = false;
                        }
                    }

        });

//Have the try catch OUTSIDE the background thread.
            try
            {
                WebClient downloadClient = new WebClient();
                downloadClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(downloadClient_OpenReadCompleted);
                downloadClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute));
                //5 of them do get here
            }
            catch
            {
                lock (filesLocker)
                {
                    --files;
                    sync.Set();
                }
                throw;
            }
```

Comment: I want to create the WebClient and call the OpenReadAsync only after I get a ++ files; for the current DownloadAsync call. So that it will only download maxFiles at once, and for the rest wait for 1 of the previous downloads to finish. (I don't get a NullReferenceException for that part when I am debugging so I guess it is created properly).