# Implement an Async timeout in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, asynchronous, delegates, timeout

In Silverlight, say we start an async request:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
```

and then wait for a response via a delegate

```
request.BeginGetResponse(getResponseResult => ...
```

How do we timeout this waitee, to deliver a time-out error signal to the delegate instead?  Use a timer?  (note: timeout options available in the .net framework are missing in the Silverlight version).

To handle two messages arriving at the same time, we could introduce a Guid filter, and then ignore a 2nd message when/if it was delivered to the delegate.  Or in reverse (better), we register an expiring Guid so that the delegate can discard a second message -- at least some garbage collection is possible then (although the memory footprint of a delegate has got to be on the small side).

What follows are some notes I've made.  I haven't reached a conclusion yet.  Any help much appreciated.

---

My line of enquiry was going to be to implement a timer, notify the callback, and then *somehow* cancel waiting delegate in request.BeginGetResponse(...).

Note:

- While the .Net Frame Work 4 implements a timeout on the WebRequest class, the Silverlight version does not.
- "System.Threading.Task.Wait Method (TimeSpan)" is not available either

> QUESTION 1: is there a better way to implement a timeout error to the same delegate target?
>
> QUESTION 2: To cancel the waiting delegate, is it sufficient to use "request.BeginGetResponse(null)"?
>
> QUESTION 3: will a non executed delegate (e.g. getResponseResult => ...) cause a small memory leak?  Is this just a minor concern?

---

Information on creating a timer:

- System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer
- http://blog.bodurov.com/How-to-Create-setTimeout-Function-in-Silverlight

Some References:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.opentimeout(v=VS.95).aspx    (seems to be WCF related)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.receivetimeout(v=VS.95).aspx (seems to be WCF related)
- http://blog.bodurov.com/How-to-Create-setTimeout-Function-in-Silverlight  (could be useful)
- [Silverlight, dealing with Async calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307844/silverlight-dealing-with-async-calls)   (no new information)
- http://petesbloggerama.blogspot.com/2008/07/omg-silverlight-asynchronous-is-evil.html  (I want to deal with Async properly... I've got some good techniques, but I want to ensure that I'm using them cleanly.  Probably I need to look into delegates more closely).
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx#CommunityContent
- http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2010/03/sequential-asynchronous-workflows-in.html  (some good information.  Still haven't found out what to do about infinitely waiting delegates).

Comment: perhaps I'm rediscovering an issue.  These people think that it can't be done with the basic classes.  An issue from 2009 no less.  See: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/74867/177780.aspx

Comment: placing the delegate in a wrapper, inside the ThreadPool sounds like a bad idea. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/6632f5f9-b650-4f16-9e8a-1a37de4970e0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you feel like giving reactive extensions a try you will get time out support for cheap. With Rx it will look something like this (not exact code):

```
var obsrv = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<...>(Begin..., End...);
obsrv(...).Timeout(new TimeSpan(0,0,5)).Subscribe(() => DoThings());
```

Comment: I hadn't explored Rx yet. This looks promissing. Here's the home page.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609

Comment: thanks for the hint.  Quite a lot of good stuff going on in this space.  http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2011/01/15/reactivexaml-is-now-reactiveui-2-0/

Comment: yep. Reactive extensions are pretty awesome :)